# What are the meanings of おはようございません and ありがとうございません?

Tags: meaning

Nobody seems to say those things.

I want to know the meanings of おはようございません and ありがとうございません.

Comment: If nobody says this why do think it has real meaning?

Comment: See also [chiebukuro - おはようございませんって言葉成立しますか？](http://m.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/detail/q1469975504). 「『早くないです』という意味で捉えられます。
これを単独で使うと違和感を覚えますが、『普段は早く来るのに、今日はお早う御座いませんね』など、文中で使えばまあちょっとおっとり目な人などなら稀に云いそうです。」

Comment: 安尾信乃助, the Osaka comedian, might want to use those.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZ7SsVq1pmQ&list=RDgooP22z4WuQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to add a bit to the **Earthliŋ**'s answer. Such standard phrases as "Good morning" are not taken at literal value, they are *formulas* to express some figurative sense. What is the literal sense of "Good morning"?

> "This morning is good", or maybe
>   "I wish you a good morning"

And what does it actually mean?

> "I greet you, and it is morning"

So, when you inflect such phrases, they immediately lose their figurative sense, and come back to the literal one, which is then inclined. Thus, "Ungood morning" would sound nothing like "I do not greet you". So the deeper level of the question is, maybe, **What is the literal meaning of such expressions like おはようございます and ありがとうございます?** And that is easy:

> おはようございます = *polite of* はやい = *lit.* "Early", meaning "How early do I meet you!"
>   ありがとうございます = *polite of* ありがたい = *lit.* "Thankful"

Now you can easily deduce their negated meanings yourself. These forms -おう are unusual for beginners, they are rare, except for several everyday expressions.

Comment: I think I get it...

Answer (score 4):

ありがとうございます and おはようございます ("Thank you very much" and "Good morning") both end in ございます, which may be inflected to its negative form ございません to give

> おはようございません
>   ありがとうございません

Like you already say yourself, these don't get used in Japanese, just like "Ungood morning" or "Few thanks" don't get used in English. I don't know where you got these expressions, but if you came up with them by yourself, you're not the first one. They're an obvious play on words, which depending on context *may* be used, e.g., to say that someone's late to work (おはようございません) etc., although generally they would probably just be interpreted as rude.