# ございます - Humble or neutral?

Tags: word-choice, words, honorifics, keigo

I was under the impression that ございます was a humble form of ある. My belief was supported by websites such as [this](http://new2japanese.blogspot.co.uk/2008/11/ix-humble-forms-of-desu-and-arimasu-de.html) and [this](http://eng.nihongodecarenavi.jp/eng/entry_5195.html). However, in the comments to [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27398/what-are-the-meanings-of-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-and-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93)'s answer, user4092 says it isn't a humble form (and also say it's used less in western Japan, which also runs contrary to my knowledge. Who is correct?

Comment: If it's a humble verb, then how is 何か御用がございましたら possible? It'd lower the opponent's affair.

Comment: I've sometimes seen it called "super-polite". As such, it's in the teineigo-spectrum, not the sonkeigo/kenjougo-spectrum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think ございます is a 丁寧語(polite form) of ある.

Sources: [Wiki敬語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%95%AC%E8%AA%9E#.E4.B8.8D.E8.A6.8F.E5.89.87.E5.8B.95.E8.A9.9E.E4.B8.80.E8.A6.A7)・[三省堂辞書](http://www.sanseido.net/main/words/hyakka/sonkei/)

～がある / ～があります -> ～がございます
～である / ～です -> ～でございます

Examples:

> 「お忘れ物の**ございませ**んようご注意ください。」
>   「ご不明な点・ご質問等が**ございまし**たら、こちらまでお問い合わせください。」

---

I live in Kansai and I don't think ございます is used more frequently here than in the east (I'm not sure if it's used less, though).

Comment: 日本語話者でもよく「『ございます』は謙譲語」と思いがちです。例えば、[例1](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q138853433)・[例2](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1471385834)