# でございます for a respected person

Tags: usage, politeness, honorifics

According to all dictionaries and most grammar books I can check, でございます is a polite form (丁寧語), which seems almost equal to です but with a more polite mood. It is classified as a humble form (謙譲語) by some people, for example in [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/27455/%E3%81%94%E3%81%96%E3%81%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99-humble-or-neutral) and also in *Japanese: A Comprehensive Grammar* published by Routledge. It should be a misclassification because でございます is used for objects whoever they belong to. But it really sometimes act like a humble form. For example, ○○様でございます is deprecated (according to [this](https://jp.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/samadegozaimasune-incorrect-correct-usage-and-example-sentences)), and 先生はお元気でございますか is said unacceptable.

If でございます being a polite form has the same property of です, it is unexplainable that

> ○○様ですか is acceptable but ○○様でございますか is not

and

> 先生はお元気ですか is acceptable but 先生はお元気でございますか is not.

I browsed some information about this and some articles say でございます cannot be used when the subject is one who you should show your respect, but can be used when talking about the possessions of that person, which is similar to a humble form.

How to explain this?

Comment: [お客様のお名前を確認する際に「〇〇様でございますか？」と聞いたり、目上の人に目上の人を紹介する際に「こちらが〇〇様でございます」と言ったりするのは正しい丁寧語の言い方です。しかし対面している相手との関係性や状況によっては、尊敬語の「いらっしゃる」を用いた方がより高い敬意を表すことができます。](https://biz.trans-suite.jp/3403)

Comment: I suppose both of what you assumed 'not acceptable' are at least not wrong. They are just overly polite, and not so common (except perhaps in specific business situations). I'd say it's more a matter of taste.

Comment: One possible explanation for what you put as “unexplainable” is that 〜でございます is superseded by more appropriate  〜でいらっしゃいます in those cases and this makes 〜でございます less common in comparison and therefore less acceptable.

Comment: The very [article](https://jp.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/samadegozaimasune-incorrect-correct-usage-and-example-sentences) you've provided from jp.indeed.com about this topic explains: ございます is the polite form of ある, whilst いらっしゃる is for  ある or いる.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

◯◯様でいらっしゃいますか is indeed more respectful (and usually more "appropriate") than ○○様でございますか, but that does not mean the latter is unacceptable or wrong. The same for お元気でいらっしゃいますか and お元気でございますか.

When the subject of a sentence is a human, there is an unequivocal honorific equivalent to です (i.e., いらっしゃる), but there is no direct humble equivalent to です in the vocabulary commonly used in modern Japanese. Therefore, it is true that ございます is much more commonly used referring to the speaker themselves than to the listener, making some people mistakenly believe ございます is a humble verb. But this is not correct. At least for me, I don't mind being asked ◯◯様でございますか in everyday business emails. It's at least much politer than ◯◯様ですか.

When the subject is an inanimate object, これは◯◯様の傘でいらっしゃいます is simply wrong; you always have to say これは◯◯様の傘でございます instead. But I'm not sure why this seemed "similar to a humble form" to you...

Comment: (See https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/30779/3097 also regarding use of inanimate subjects with いらっしゃる)